# Add Custom Fieldset Without making a Core module Rewrite

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides

I am wondering, is there any way to add a custom fieldset to an admin form, without overwriting Form container class of that admin-form.

I will explain it little bit. Suppose we need to add a new fieldset in `CMS_Block`. We can achieve this by rewrite `_preapreForm()` method of class  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form`. Here we need to do somewhat this in order to achieve our goal

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Block_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form{
    
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();

        /*
           add new fieldset and fields here
        */
    }
}
```

However I don't like to do rewrite of a core class (Since Its not a good practice). Is there any other approach exist to achieve the same result. I just want to add a new field sets with a custom module on an admin form with two conditions

1. Without touching core files
2. Without doing rewrite

Comment: What is about layout update? Or using event for specific controller/action render?

Comment: @Amasty   layout update wont work. Please review the answer that marius made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to observe the event `adminhtml_block_html_before`.
but that gets dispatched for every block that is a child of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template`.
So you will need to to a check first to see if the block matches your need.
something like this:

```
public function addFields($observer) {
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form) {
         //do your magic here
    }
}
```

Comment: observers are better than rewrite. But still its not a clean method. Coz almost every admin blocks are child of `Mage_Admin_Html_Template`. Is there any way to achieve this through layout ? But when I deeply thinking about it, it gave me a feeling that, my block would include outside of the form. @marius

Comment: @programmer_rkt I don't think there is a way to do it through layout files. The block in question does not appear in the layout files. It is instantiated via the parent block.

Comment: and secondly I have a friendly question to you. Which method you normally adopt to do this job?

Comment: So as per your suggestion, there is probably these two ways exist to do this right ?

Comment: i suggest that this as event every time for admin block,if you add controller full action name as ccondtion then it it be better.....$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
$action->getFullActionName()
if($action->getFullActionName()='adminhtml_cms_block_edit){

// marius code
}

Comment: @programmer_rkt. I usually try to avoid observing general events like this one. But it depends. If I need to do this for a specific project for sure I will rewrite the block, but for a community extension I might go with the event. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @AmitBera : so you recommends observer method in this case. Good to know. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Marius : You are going for event observer in case of extension, may be due to avoid rewrite problems that may cause by your extension right ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt. Yep. that'e the exact reason.

Comment: @Marius : thanks for this great knowledge share with me. I am now developing an extension. For that I need to do this. It will definitely help to create  good extensions. And thanks for following me.!!! I am extremely happy :)

Comment: @DRAJI. this is not in the topic of this question. Let's keep it clean. There is an e-mail address in the code files of the module creator. Send me an e-mail there and I'll answer as soon as I can.